# Edit GeoJSON attribute table

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geojson

Is it possible to adjust tabel headers of GeoJSON files in ArcGIS?

If yes, which max length has a row header?

In QGIS there is no possibility to edit a GeoJSON table.

Comment: You can use the **Table Mangager** plugin. It allows you to re-arrange the whole attribute table and also to change the name of a GeoJSON header file

Comment: To clarify @matteo, Table Manager is a plugin for QGIS.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup you are right. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS you can just transfer the layer to a memory layer, edit it, then transfer it back to GeoJSON. (or use a shapefile instead of a memory layer).

See: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EditAnyLayer/

However, if I remember correctly, Table Manager (as mentioned by matteo) lets you edit these headers and the rest of the structure, for many files including GeoJSON.
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/

In order to do this in ArcGIS you need to convert the file to a shapefile or geodatabase (or use a plugin), then edit it as that format, then re-export as a GeoJSON.